# Unable to set the HUD launcher key

Tags: hud

I was finding that the left Alt key for opening the HUD was not working, so I went to Keyboard Shortcuts to re-set it. Selecting the shortcut to set it and pressing the Alt key just sets it to 'Disabled', however.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dconf command, open your terminal to type:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '["&lt;Alt&gt;"]'
```

This should restore the HUD default key to "Alt Left"